# jqm popup is not opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I added a popup to a div-container. Opening the popup doesn't work.

This is my container-structure:

```
 <div data-role="page" id="mainPage">
    <div id="myContent">  <!--div id="myContent" data-role="content/main"> dosn't work either -->
        <div id="template" style="display:none;">
            <a class="select-Button">
               ...
            </a>
        </div>
        <ul data-role="list-view"></ul>
        <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup">
            <p>My Popup</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to open the popup by javascript:

```
...clone the template and add clones to the list-view before.
$('#mainPage').find('.select-Button').on('click', function(){
    $('#myPopup').popup("open");
});
```

But it's not working

This works:

Java-Script:

```
        var $popUp = $('#myPopup').popup({
            dismissible: false,
            theme: "c",
            overlyaTheme: "d",
            transition: "pop"
        });
        $popUp.popup('open').trigger("create");
```

HTML:

```
<div id="myPopup">   <!-- removed data-role="popup" here-->
            <p>My Popup</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

*page* div should be direct parent of *popup* div. If you place it inside any other div, it won't open, or malfunction.

```
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup">
     <p>My Popup</p>
  </div>
<div id="myContent">
  <div id="template" style="display:none;">
 </div>
 <ul data-role="list-view"></ul>
</div>
```

To open it using HTML

```
<a href="#popupID" data-rel="popup">Popup</a>
```

To open programatically

```
$("#popupID").popup("open");
```

---

You need to delegate `click` event to dynamically added elements.

```
$(document).on("click", ".select-button", function () {
  $('#myPopup').popup("open");
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/5Y3Rr/)**

Comment: It's not working in phonegap, I need to check if it's a phonegap issue.

Comment: @marcel it depends how/when do you open it.

Comment: I'm listening to click-events of  select-buttons I add to the list-view. If a button is clicked, I want to open the popup. I'll add that to my post.

Comment: @marcel so those buttons are dynamically added?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49925/discussion-between-omar-and-marcel)

Comment: I've found another contribute by you in another post. now I removed the data-role"popup" from the dom container. I put the changes into my question.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/rF873/

**JS:-**

```
$('#myPopup').popup();    
$('#myPopup').popup("open");
```

**HTML:-**

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div id="myContent">  <!--div id="myContent" data-role="content/main"> dosn't work either -->
        <div id="template" style="display:none;">
        </div>
        <ul data-role="list-view"></ul>
        <div dara-role="popup" id="myPopup">
            <p>My Popup</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Issue with your approach is that you cannot call methods on popup prior to initialization.**

Comment: use `.popup()` only when you want to initialize _popup_ manually. When it's static, you don't need to call `.popup()`.