# jQuery Mobile popup not appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have the following popup in my header:

```
<div data-role="header">
  <h1>Home</h1>
    <a href="#popupMenu" data-rel="popup" data-transition="slide" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-a">Menu</a>
    <div data-role="popup" id="popupMenu"  data-theme="a" style="top: 22px; right: -12px">
      <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="min-width:250px; min-height: 698px;">
        <li><a href="test1.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="test2.html">Second</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

When i click on a link to go to the next page, on tapping the header button, the menu popup does not appear.

If i refresh the URL it appears. Also in the URL i see the text `#&ui-state=dialog`

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jqm popup is not opening](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22474123/jqm-popup-is-not-opening)

Comment: popup should be outside any div. if it's _internal_, page div should be the direct parent of it. if it's _external_, `body` should be direct parent.