# jQuery mobile on click function

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I am just starting with jQuery Mobile I want to create popup.

I found the following example on the jQuery Mobile site:

```
<a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup">Open Popup</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
    <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.<p>
    <a href="index.html" data-role="button">Link button</a> 
    <a href="index.html" data-role="button">Link button</a> 
</div>
```

That works very well. What I need now is to change that from an `href` to an `onClick` function like this below:

```
<a href="#" onclick="popupBasic" data-rel="popup">Open Popup</a>
```

Its not working like that. What should I put to `onClick` to make it work?

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't know anything on JS, but I think that onclick should have assigned a function... something like popupBasic( ).

Comment: I know it should. But it is not simply like that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jqm popup is not opening](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22474123/jqm-popup-is-not-opening)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use as below:

Create javascript function :

```
 function openPopUp(){
        $('#popupBasic').popup('open'); 
    }
```

call openPopUp() in click event as below :

```
<a href="#" onclick="openPopUp()" data-rel="popup">Open Popup</a>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Y3Rr/2/)

Comment: does you have append function below to your link

Comment: Works beuatifull. Thank you